# Forward declare free function in template class

Tags: c++, templates

I think I need some tutoring on templates, especially in conjunction with inheritance. I am well aware those two concepts don't play very well together.
We've wanted to get ride of clang tidy warnings, but I have no clue how to achieve it.

The abstracted code is below, please see https://godbolt.org/z/sPfx7Yhad to compile it.
The setting is, we have some abstract base class (`Animal`), and a specialized type (`Dog`).
A converter functionality can only be defined on the base class.

There is a templated reader class, which is templated with the actual specialized typed (`Reader<Dog>`).

However, clang-tidy complains when analyzing `reader.h`, as `converter::convert` is not known.
It's only known in `main.cpp`, by including `converter.h` before `reader.h`.

I have tried to forward declare the function by using template:

```
namespace converter
{
  template<typename T>
  void convert(const std::string& input, T& animal);
}
```

Which leads to linker errors, because now the linker is looking for a `void convert(const std::string&, Dog&)` implemenation, rather than using the `void convert(cons std::string&, Animal&)` overload. (see https://godbolt.org/z/x4cPfh6P4)

What can I do? How could I change the design to avoid the clang-tidy warning?
In general, I cannot add the actual includes to `converter.h` in `reader.h`, as that part is generic and the user shall be able to use the reader with their own types, by providing a custom converter functionality.

What I *cannot* change are classes `Dog` and `Animal`. They are autogenerated classes / libraries which we are using.

For anyone who is interested, the real world example can be found here https://github.com/continental/ecal/blob/master/samples/cpp/measurement/measurement_read/src/measurement_read.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// animal.h
// class hierarchy with abstract base class
class Animal
{
public:
   std::string name;
   virtual std::string what() = 0;
};

// dog.h
class Dog : public Animal
{ 
public:
  std::string what() override {return "dog";}
};

// animal_converter.h 
// converting function
// #include <animal.h>
namespace converter 
{
  void convert(const std::string& input, Animal& animal)
  {
    animal.name = input;
  }
}

// reader.h
// Templated class for reader functionality
template <typename T>
class Reader
{
public:
  T read()
  {
    T output;
    converter::convert("Anton", output);
    return output;
  }
};

// main.cpp
// #include dog.h
// #include animal_converter.h
// #include reader.h
int main()
{
  Reader<Dog> reader;
  std::cout << reader.read().name << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of making the `convert` function into a template?

Comment: I cannot include the actual implemenation in `reader.h` as it might be user defined. Think about reader as a generic library, while `converter` is specific functionality for user types.

Comment: I don't know how I would forward declare it, if it wasn't for a template, and I don't know what types may be used for it

Comment: Perhaps you need to rethink the design somewhat. The `Animal` hierarchy doesn't share much with the `Buildings` and `Books` hierarchies, but they do share this `convert` thingy. Perhaps the base classes for all these branches should inherit from an `IConvertible` base which has a `virtual void convert(const std::string&) = 0;` member function?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. They are serialization base classes like `google::protobuf::Message` from google protobuf, and the inherited classes are auto generated. 
But maybe I need to introduce another class, which has this as member, and also provides the functionality.

Comment: You only need to implement `convert` in each stems base, like `Animal`. You don't need to touch `Dog`. Is `Animal` also auto generated?

Comment: Or I need to have `Reader<Type, Converter>`  and provide conversion functionality in a separate class.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if you can read my comments under a deleted post so I'll answer here: Ok, I see the problem and perhaps your alternative method is the way to go. If it doesn't work out and you ask a question about that, please make sure that you specify what you can and cannot change in the classes involved :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry I realized that the question was not 100% clear from the start, I will edit it appropriately. Thanks for the effort that you took!